# How to sort array by date modified in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

Use I am using sketchware IDE. How can I sort the the list by date or time modified.

I used this code

```
Arrays.sort(list, new Comparator<File>(){ 
 @Override public int compare(File file1, File file2)
  { 
      long k = file1.lastModified() - file2.lastModified();
       if(k > 0)
       { return 1; }
       else 
       if(k == 0)
       { return 0; }
       else
       { return -1; 
           } 
           }
            }
            );
```

But I get an error:

```
The method sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<String>, new Comparator<File>(){})
```

Comment: Please post the code in which you populate `list` array.

Comment: Use `Collections.sort` instead of `Arrays.sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.sort() doesn't seem to accept a List.

So if you want to use Arrays.sort(), you should first convert the list to an array, like this:

```
File[] filesArray = new File[files.size()];
filesArray = files.toArray(filesArray);
```

Then call the function with the filesArray variable.

Comment: Got error again

Comment: Note that I used "files", instead of "list". Could that be the problem? Can you share the code?